# If don't send any id an URL how to handle that error in react js

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have hit a URL and by mistake, I forgot to send the id. how to handle it?

here is the sample code
App.js

```
import Filter from './component/Filter';
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Filter />
        <Route path="/searchById/:id" exact component={Filter} />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10qTL.png)

when I send some id it's working fine. But if I don't give any id I want to display some error message like id must be mandatory.

Comment: Did you use Router and Switch?

Comment: Router only i m using

Comment: I do not see any usage of word `Router` in the code in your question.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the all routes just use a `*` route or a not found route which will indicate if any route doesn't exist

```
import Filter from './component/Filter';
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Filter />
        <Route path="/searchById/:id" exact component={Filter} />
        <Route path='/searchById/*' exact component={NotFoundComponent} />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It will work but when I am sending the proper URL data is coming as well as that error message is still displaying.

Comment: Oh I didn't see `:` before `id`... You can easily handle this by implementing a `if/else` block. Just show a Component which says NOT FOUND or similar human readable error message. You will use cached data in state or get the data with that `:id` via fetch or similar mechanism.. If you don't find any data or the API returns some kind of 404 message then the Error Component or UI will be shown... That's it